# Write quotes round all fields except first (heading) row

Tags: c#, csvhelper

CsvHelper has this very handy flag to set `""` round all fields (a common requirement in CSV files):

```
csv.Configuration.QuoteAllFields = true;
```

However, this also places `"` round the first row, which contains field names.

How can `""` be put round all fields except the first row containing field names?

I can find nothing in Google

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: Client requirement

Comment: Show the entire code you use to write the file

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this

```
cw.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => context.HasHeaderBeenWritten;
```

or

```
cw.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => context.Row > 1;
```

But you'll need to test and adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the code of csvhelper it appears that the WriteHeader methods use WriteField internally, and set flags indicating that the header has been written. WriteField obeys the currently configured settings as to whether it should quote a field or not, and it bakes the quotes into the field data passed at the time it is called even though writing to the file doesn't necessarily occur at that time

As such I recommend you do something like this:

```
var cw = new CsvWriter(yourTextWriterOrWhatever);
cw.Configuration.QuoteNoFields = true;
cw.WriteHeader<YourClassNameHere>();
cw.NextRecord(); // without this first row is on same line as header
cw.Configuration.QuoteAllFields = true; //or set QuoteNoFields = false
cw.WriteRecords(yourCollectionOfYourClass);
```

Just to be clear; you cannot paste and go on this code above, you have to edit it to be valid to your context - anywhere you encounter he word "Your" needs adjusting.

The important part I'm aiming to outline is that you should

- turn quotes off in the config,
- write the headers,
- turn quoting on (either by quoting everything or disabling the quotenofields and letting csvhelper work out whether to quote or not)
- write the data records

Comment: QuoteAllFields appears to have stopped working in version 2? It's no longer available.

Comment: Both 2.x https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/2.x/#configuration-quote-all-fields and 3.x  https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/configuration#writing documentation still reference it?

Comment: A commit 17 days ago indicates that these have indeed been removed in favor of ShouldQuote - https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/commit/83683e087f31626629c9973d2e1cb66940b82651

Comment: This works - Note you need to call NextRecord after WriteHeader - or the first row of data will be written on the same line as the header.

Answer (score 0):

From version 25.0.0 up to the date, the way of achieving this is:

```
 new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
 {
     ShouldQuote = args => args.Row.HeaderRecord != null,
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

With CsvHelper V27.2.1 this is done with:

```
 new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                HasHeaderRecord = true,
                ShouldQuote = x => x.Row.Row > 1,
            };
```